# How to convert a date in special pattern using excel formula

Tags: excel

System returns date in such format:

> January 24th 2018, 08:43:04.458

Is there a possibility to convert it into:

```
2018-12-24 08:43:04
```

Was trying to find something using google but unsuccessfully.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: this -> 2018-12-24 08:43:04

Comment: `2018-12-24` = **December** 24th 2018.  Are you sure you want to convert the **January** to **December** or is that a typo.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was my mistake ,thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do **NOT** want to convert **January** to **12**, but rather to **01**, and your example is a typo, you can try this:

```
=LEFT(REPLACE(A1,MIN(SEARCH({"st";"nd";"rd";"th"},A1&"stndrdth")),2,", "),LEN(A1)-14)+RIGHT(A1,12)
```

Then format however you want.

The formula converts the string to a date recognizable by Excel by

- converting the ordinal to a cardinal number
- inserting a comma after the **day**
- removing the time portion
- add (rather than concatenate) the time function

to convert both to an Excel date/time value.

That value can then be formatted by the usual custom number formatting procedure.

*If your system months are not English, a more complicated formula may be required*.

Comment: it's perfect, thanks a lot!!!